# RelativeLayout parameters programmatically align error

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying programmatically align some elements in RelativeLayout but I am getting some problem. All my TextView elements aligned to the top left corner even when I set them deferentially. here is my screen shot:
[image]

Here is my code (`this` is the RelativeLayout):

```
        title = new TextView(context);
        date = new TextView(context);
        rating = new RatingBar(context);
        saleImage = new ImageView(context);
        arrowImage = new ImageView(context);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
        this.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
        this.setClickable(true);

        relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        saleImage.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
        saleImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.rihanna);
        this.addView(saleImage);

        relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        arrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
        arrowImage.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
        this.addView(arrowImage);

        relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, saleImage.getId());
        title.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
        title.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
        title.setText("Sale title");
        this.addView(title);

        relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        relativeLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 26, 0);
        relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, arrowImage.getId());
        date.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
        date.setText("14.01.13 22:00");
        this.addView(date);
```

It seems that the problem is with the `RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF` and `RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF` attributes.

here is the Activity code:

```
public class MainPage extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout test;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_sales);

        test = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.salesConteiner);
        SaleRow row = new SaleRow(this);
        test.addView(row);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Is there something I have missed? Thanks!!!

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185368/android-dynamic-relativelayout-overlaps-each-other) can help you.

Comment: Try creating a new `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` object for each view, instead of reusing the same `relativeLayoutParams` object.

Comment: @John Leehey it didn't help

Comment: @Noah I have added the Activity code, I am allready using LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

For the `view.getId()` function to work you first need to se an id: `view.setId(1)`.

Thanks for the help!!!